# How to add simple graphics to a game to add scrolling text on screen?

Tags: python, graphics

I am making a text adventure game and want to be able to have graphics that make the text go on the screen and scroll through like undertale text. How can I do this?

Comment: What are you using for the UI? For example, you could be using `tkinter`, `pgreloaded` or just the console.

Comment: anything that works and is easy to add to my current code to make graphics. So tkinter

Comment: I recommend using `tkinter`. It's good for making simple graphical interfaces, and pretty easy to learn. I will post an answer explaining a way you could do this soon.

Comment: One thing you'll need to look out for is that tkinter comes with Python on Windows and macOS, but Linux users will need to download it separately.

Answer (score 1):

This solution here works.

```
from tkinter import *; # Import the Tk library.

import time; # So that we can use the time library
import math; # And perform maths operations

tk = Tk(); # Make a new window
tk.title("Not Undertale"); # Set the title of the window. You can change this if you like.
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=600, height=400); # Make a canvas that we can put the text on. You can play around with the numbers if you like.
canvas.pack(); # This basically tells Tk to find somewhere to put the canvas.
text = "         Hello. This goes on forever."; # This is the message that will scroll across the screen. You can change this, although I reccommend putting at least on space either before or after the text.
txt = canvas.create_text(300, 200, text = "          ", font = ("Monospace", 12)); # This creates the item that will hold the widget. Again, you can play around with the numbers. The font is Monospace size 12, this is optional. I reccommend using a fixed-width font for this though.

timer = 0; # The timer.
count = 0; # A variable that we will use later.

while True:
    try:
        tk.update(); # The reason this is in a Try/Except statement is because you get errors when you close the window, so we want to ignore that and finish the program.
    except:
        break;
    time.sleep(0.05); # Wait a bit before drawing the next frame
    timer += 0.05; # And add a bit to timer
    count = math.floor(timer * 4) % len(text); # This is where we use the count variable. Basically this changes by 1 every frame, we use this to find what part of the text we're writing.
    if count > len(text): # If the count variable is more than the length of the text, set it to 0.
        count = 0; # I'm positive we don't need this bit, but it's in there just in case.
    display_txt = ""; # This is a temporary variable where we store the scrolling letters.
    c = count; # Copy the count variable to one called c
    while c < count + 10: # While c is between count and ten more than count.
        display_txt += text[c % len(text)]; # We add a letter to display_txt
        c += 1; # And add one to c.
    canvas.itemconfig(txt, text = display_txt); # The last thing we need to do is change the content of the text item so that it displays the scrolled text.
```

This is probably not the best way of doing it, but it works, and you can experiment with it.

Comment: Its recommende to include `import` staements on the top of the code

Comment: Good point. I moved them to the top.